# Cannot save calculation data by category when create new data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, sum, laravel-query-builder

### Model SpentTime

I am unable save calculation data by category when create new data in laravel

```
public static function findOrCreate($plan_id, $data)
{
    $fromDate = Carbon::now()->subDay()->startOfWeek()->toDateString();
    $nowDate = Carbon::now()->today()->toDateString();

    $spent_time = static::where('plan_id', $plan_id)->first();

    if (is_null($spent_time)) {
        return static::create($data);
    }else{
        $task_category = SpentTime::where('task_category', $spent_time->task_category)->get();
        $create_spent_times = SpentTime::where('task_category', $spent_time->task_category)->sum('daily_spent_time', $fromDate);
        $request['spent_time'] = (int)$create_spent_times + $spent_time->daily_spent_time;

        $create_spent_times = SpentTime::where('task_category', $spent_time->task_category)->sum('daily_percentage', $fromDate);
        $request['percentage'] = (int)$create_spent_times + $spent_time->daily_percentage;

        $spent_time->save();
        return $spent_time->update($data);
    }
}
```

### TrackerController

This is the controller function to store data:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{      
    $spent_time = SpentTime::findOrCreate($request->get('plan_id'), [
        'plan_id' => $request->get ('plan_id'),
        'daily_spent_time' => $request->get ('daily_spent_time'),
        'daily_percentage' => $request->get ('daily_percentage'),
        'reason' => $request->get ('reason')
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('real.index', compact( 'spent_time'));
}
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: what the error message ?

Comment: @linuxartisan sum up values ​​that have been created previously based on the same category, when you want to create new data in the same category.

Comment: @AriPratomo no error, but can calculate the data based on the category, only can I save the data, can't calculate the data

Comment: What is the `$request` array data used for in the `findorCreate()` function?

Comment: @thisiskelvin yes, because the data is input form, so use a ` $request `, is there a solution?

Comment: `$request` is not being passed down into this function at all, which means its not being used

Comment: What is `$task_category` being used for in the function?

Comment: $task_category to look for task_category in the tables spent_times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Model

```
public static function findOrCreate($plan_id, $data)
{
    $spent_time = static::where('plan_id', $plan_id)->first();
    $task_category = $spent_time->task_category;

    if (is_null($spent_time)) {
        return static::create($data);
    }else{
        $spent_time['spent_time'] = $spent_time->spent_time + $spent_time->daily_spent_time;
        $spent_time['percentage'] = $spent_time->percentage  + $spent_time->daily_percentage;

    return $spent_time->update($data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update Answer

> can create new data, but can not calculate data by category

[image]

### Model

```
public static function findOrCreate($plan_id, $data)
{
    $fromDate = Carbon::now()->subDay()->startOfWeek();
    $nowDate = Carbon::now()->today();

    $spent_time = static::where('plan_id', $plan_id)->first();
    if (is_null($spent_time)) {
        return static::create($data);
    }else{
        $new_spent_time = SpentTime::first();
        $task_category = $new_spent_time->task_category;

        $new_spent_time->task_category = (['{task_category}' => $task_category, 
                                        '{daily_spent_time}' => $new_spent_time->daily_spent_time,
                                        '{daily_percentage}' => $new_spent_time->daily_percentage,
                                        '{spent_time}' => $new_spent_time->spent_time,
                                        '{percentage}' => $new_spent_time->percentage, $new_spent_time->task_category]);

        $new_spent_time->spent_time = $new_spent_time::where('task_category',$task_category)
                                    ->sum('daily_spent_time', $new_spent_time->daily_spent_time , $fromDate);
        $new_spent_time['spent_time'] = (int)$new_spent_time->spent_time + $spent_time->daily_spent_time;

        $new_spent_time->percentage = $new_spent_time::where('task_category',$task_category)
                                    ->sum('daily_percentage', $new_spent_time->daily_percentage, $fromDate);
        $new_spent_time['percentage'] = (int)$new_spent_time->percentage  + $spent_time->daily_percentage;
        return $spent_time->update($data);
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{      
    $spent_time = SpentTime::findOrCreate($request->get('plan_id'), [
        'plan_id' => $request->get ('plan_id'),
        'daily_spent_time' => $request->get ('daily_spent_time'),
        'daily_percentage' => $request->get ('daily_percentage'),
        'reason' => $request->get ('reason'),
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('real.index', compact( 'spent_time'));
}
```