# Error: Trying to get property of non-object when creating or saving data

Tags: php, laravel, sum, laravel-query-builder, laravel-5.7

[image]

> "Trying to get property of non-object"

**Model**

When creating new data and want to save, an error occurs as above

```
public static function findOrCreate($plan_id, $data)
{
    $fromDate = Carbon::now()->subDay()->startOfWeek();
    $nowDate = Carbon::now()->today();

    $spent_time = static::where('plan_id', $plan_id)->first();

    if (is_null($spent_time)) {
        return static::create($data);
    }else{
        $new_spent_time = SpentTime::find($plan_id);
        $task_category = $new_spent_time->task_category;

        $new_spent_time->task_category = (['{task_category}' => $task_category, 
                                        '{daily_spent_time}' => $new_spent_time->daily_spent_time,
                                        '{daily_percentage}' => $new_spent_time->daily_percentage,
                                        '{spent_time}' => $new_spent_time->spent_time,
                                        '{percentage}' => $new_spent_time->percentage, $new_spent_time->task_category]);

        $new_spent_time->spent_time = $new_spent_time::where('task_category',$task_category)
                                    ->sum('daily_spent_time', $new_spent_time->daily_spent_time , $fromDate);
        $request['spent_time'] = (int)$new_spent_time->spent_time + $spent_time->daily_spent_time;

        $new_spent_time->percentage = $new_spent_time::where('task_category',$task_category)
                                    ->sum('daily_percentage', $new_spent_time->daily_percentage, $fromDate);
        $request['percentage'] = (int)$new_spent_time->percentage  + $spent_time->daily_percentage;
        $new_spent_time->save();

        return $spent_time->update($data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`"Trying to get property of non-object"` means the property doesn't exist

change your `find` to `findOrFail`

```
$new_spent_time = SpentTime::findOrFail($plan_id);
```

this way, laravel will return an error when it doesn't find a record in the database.

another way is check if your query has succeeded:

```
$new_spent_time = SpentTime::find($plan_id);
if($new_spent_time){

    $task_category = $new_spent_time->task_category;

    $new_spent_time->task_category = (['{task_category}' => $task_category, 
                                    '{daily_spent_time}' => $new_spent_time->daily_spent_time,
                                    '{daily_percentage}' => $new_spent_time->daily_percentage,
                                    '{spent_time}' => $new_spent_time->spent_time,
                                    '{percentage}' => $new_spent_time->percentage, $new_spent_time->task_category]);

    $new_spent_time->spent_time = $new_spent_time::where('task_category',$task_category)
                                ->sum('daily_spent_time', $new_spent_time->daily_spent_time , $fromDate);
    $request['spent_time'] = (int)$new_spent_time->spent_time + $spent_time->daily_spent_time;

    $new_spent_time->percentage = $new_spent_time::where('task_category',$task_category)
                                ->sum('daily_percentage', $new_spent_time->daily_percentage, $fromDate);
    $request['percentage'] = (int)$new_spent_time->percentage  + $spent_time->daily_percentage;
    $new_spent_time->save();

    return $spent_time->update($data);
}else{
    return 'no result found';
}
```

Comment: but, page not found. is there another solution?

Comment: when saving create new data with the same category.

Comment: it means laravel didn't find any record in your database. try returning `$plan_id` and see what data it return then compare it in your database if that `id` really exist.

Comment: If you use $new_spent_time = SpentTime::findorfail($plan_id);, the page is not found. but if use $new_spent_time = SpentTime::get();  error like this "Property [task_category] does not exist on this collection instance."

Comment: Route::resource('/real', 'TrackerController');

Comment: your route using `public static function findOrCreate`

Comment: what does it say?

Comment: I mean can you show your route using the `public static function findOrCreate`?
`Route::resource('/real', 'TrackerController');` doesn't use that specific function

Comment: sorry i don't understand your point yet, can you help me please

Comment: in your `routes.php`, show me the `route` that uses the function `findOrCreate`.
like `Route::post('/sample','SampleController@findOrCreate');`

Comment: you can check link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52865862/cannot-save-calculation-data-by-category-when-create-new-data-in-laravel, can you help me ?

Comment: because in the controller I made a call to the model

Answer (score 0):

> it should be when storing the data that is created will go to the form and calculate the amount of data

[image]