# Property [task_category] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, sum, laravel-query-builder, laravel-5.7

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8LGL.png)

### Model in Laravel

> "Property [task_category] does not exist on this collection instance."

```
public static function findOrCreate($plan_id, $data)
{
    $fromDate = Carbon::now()->subDay()->startOfWeek();
    $nowDate = Carbon::now()->today();

    $spent_time = static::where('plan_id', $plan_id)->first();

    if (is_null($spent_time)) {
        return static::create($data);
    }else{
    $new_spent_time = SpentTime::get();
    $new_spent_time->task_category = (['{task_category}' => $new_spent_time->task_category, 
                                        '{daily_spent_time}' => $new_spent_time->daily_spent_time,
                                        '{daily_percentage}' => $new_spent_time->daily_percentage,
                                        '{spent_time}' => $new_spent_time->spent_time,
                                        '{percentage}' => $new_spent_time->percentage, $new_spent_time->task_category]);

        $new_spent_time->spent_time = $new_spent_time::where('task_category',$task_category)
                                    ->sum('daily_spent_time', $new_spent_time->daily_spent_time , $fromDate);
        $request['spent_time'] = (int)$new_spent_time->spent_time + $spent_time->daily_spent_time;

        $new_spent_time->percentage = $new_spent_time::where('task_category',$task_category)
                                    ->sum('daily_percentage', $new_spent_time->daily_percentage, $fromDate);
        $request['percentage'] = (int)$new_spent_time->percentage  + $spent_time->daily_percentage;
        return $spent_time->update($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the `task_category` field in your `spenttime` table migration?

Comment: @thisiskelvin Yes, of course

Comment: What is your `SpentTime::get()` function intended for? Is it to get the first instance? Create a new one? if if to get the first, use `::first()`.

Comment: @thisiskelvin thank's, but there is one more problem, when saving create new data, data that has the same category cannot be calculated yet, I ask for help. 
please, you can see link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52865862/cannot-save-calculation-data-by-category-when-create-new-data-in-laravel

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52884984/when-creating-new-data-and-want-to-save-error-trying-to-get-property-of-non-obj

Comment: I'll check this out

Comment: Update the question with this answer too.

Comment: @thisiskelvin ok, thank's

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using `first()` rather than `get()`:

```
$new_spent_time = SpentTime::first();
```

Answer (score 0):

### Model

```
public static function findOrCreate($plan_id, $data)
{
    $fromDate = Carbon::now()->subDay()->startOfWeek();
    $nowDate = Carbon::now()->today();

    $spent_time = static::where('plan_id', $plan_id)->first();
    if (is_null($spent_time)) {
        return static::create($data);
    }else{
        $new_spent_time = SpentTime::first();
        $task_category = $new_spent_time->task_category;

        $new_spent_time->task_category = (['{task_category}' => $task_category, 
                                        '{daily_spent_time}' => $new_spent_time->daily_spent_time,
                                        '{daily_percentage}' => $new_spent_time->daily_percentage,
                                        '{spent_time}' => $new_spent_time->spent_time,
                                        '{percentage}' => $new_spent_time->percentage, $new_spent_time->task_category]);

        $new_spent_time->spent_time = $new_spent_time::where('task_category',$task_category)
                                    ->sum('daily_spent_time', $new_spent_time->daily_spent_time , $fromDate);
        $new_spent_time['spent_time'] = (int)$new_spent_time->spent_time + $spent_time->daily_spent_time;

        $new_spent_time->percentage = $new_spent_time::where('task_category',$task_category)
                                    ->sum('daily_percentage', $new_spent_time->daily_percentage, $fromDate);
        $new_spent_time['percentage'] = (int)$new_spent_time->percentage  + $spent_time->daily_percentage;

        return $spent_time->update($data);
    }
}
```